# Script doesn't run after logging in as admin but works fine if admin not required

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app that works fine. I'm trying to make one of the scripts only run if the user is an admin (me). The admin login works fine but then I get redirected to the page /geocode and nothing happens. I see an HTTP Response of 200.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT 2: To add full code on request.

app.yaml:

```
application: theapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /geocode
  script: geocode.py
  login: admin

- url: /admin/.*
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/admin
  login: admin

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon\.ico

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: first.py
  secure: never

builtins:
- appstats: on

inbound_services:
- warmup
```

first.py:

```
import os

from beer import Beer
from desktop import Desktop
from geocode import Geocode


from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
        [('/', Desktop),
        ('/beer', Beer),
        ('/geocode', Geocode)],
        debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

geocode.py:

```
import pubs
import os
import time


from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

import urllib
import urllib2
import simplejson

class Geocode(webapp.RequestHandler):
    '''Class for ./geocode 
    A couple of methods to take the address' from the Pubs.pub_address array
    and turn them into usefull Latitudes & Longitudes.
    '''
    def get_lat_long(self, location):
        place = urllib.quote_plus(location)
        print location
        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=true&region=no" % (place)
        print url 
        out = urllib.urlopen(url)
        jsonResponse = simplejson.load(out)
        pub_location = jsonResponse.get('results')[0].get('geometry').get('location')
        lat = pub_location.get('lat')
        lng = pub_location.get('lng')
        return lat, lng

    def get(self):
        pub_address = []
        pub_bounce = []
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
        path = os.path.join(path, 'geocode.html')

        for i, element in enumerate(pubs.pub_list):
            pub_bounce.append(pubs.pub_list[i].pub_bounce)

        for i, element in enumerate(pubs.pub_list):
            pub_address.append(pubs.pub_list[i].pub_address.encode('utf-8'))

        for i, element in enumerate(pub_address):
            pubs.pub_list[i].pub_lat, pubs.pub_list[i].pub_lng = self.get_lat_long(pub_address[i])
            print pubs.pub_list[i].pub_lat, pubs.pub_list[i].pub_lng
            time.sleep(.2)


        template_values = {"pub_address": pub_address, "pub_bounce": pub_bounce}
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Comment: Shouldn't login under /geocode be login:required rather than admin?

Comment: Anything you can provide on the workings of /geocode?

Comment: /geocode takes some address from a data model and turns them into lat/lng. As I mentioned, it works fine if the handler for /geocode is removed. "login: admin" is for users who are logged-in and admins. "login: required" seems to be just for any user that is logged in.

Comment: Any chance you could post anything from geocode? Just wondering if you have some sort of condition stopping the script from proceeding.

Comment: A 'rough outline' isn't sufficient - you need to show us code that definitely reproduces the issue you're seeing, even if it's not the same as your actual code. For instance, the code you paste omits the application declaration - but I can't tell if that's the problem, because you haven't included everything.

Comment: Full code added as requested. Thanks again to those looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
- url: /geocode   
  script: first.py   
  login: admin
```

The scripts referenced from app.yaml need to be an application handler (eg have run_wsgi_app etc in them). geocode.py is not an application handler - it's some code imported by first.py.

Answer (score 1):

Does your geocode.py pass variables via POST method?

In my experience, while redirect to the "login" page, the variables passed by POST method will lose. (the variables passed by GET will remains) 
Then it will result the situation that response with 200 but nothing really happens.

> ```
> # app.yaml
> application: xxx
> version: 1
> runtime: python
> api_version: 1
>
>
> handlers:
> - url: /test\.html
>   static_files: test.html
>   upload: test.html
>
> - url: /
>   login: admin
>   script: urls.py
> ```

```
# urls.py
from google.appengine.ext import db, webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import logging

class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        print "get"
        print self.request.get("var")

        logging.info("GET %s"%self.request.get("var"))

    def post(self):
        print "post"
        print self.request.get("var")

        logging.info("POST %s"%self.request.get("var"))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/', Test),])

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

#===============================================================================
# # it is necessary; otherwise, it will cause the server won't response 
# # at the first request which create a instance
#===============================================================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


<!-- test.html -->
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            <input type="text" name="var" value="123">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've edited my question to show that the Geocode script creates two lists that get passed to the view. no POST there but thank you for taking the time to help :)